# Create indexes AND deploy as read-only

Tags: neo4j

I want to expose my graph securely (read-only), but also want to create indexes on properties. AFAIK, indexes can only be created on a graph that allows write access...Am I missing something?

How do I deploy a read-only Neo4J graph, that has had indexes created on certain properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the enterprise edition of neo4j does let you create users with the read-only `reader` [role](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/authentication-authorization/built-in-roles/), that does not prevent you from creating other users with a different role that permits write access.

So, there is no problem with creating indexes even if there are some users who only have read-only access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the community edition, one way to achieve this is to:

1. generate the graph first by starting it up,
2. creating the indices,
3. shut it down and
4. start it up again with in read-only mode with indices already created.